# Removing special characters in bash

Tags: linux, sed, character

I have a variable "text" which contains the value `"IN▒ENJERING"`
`Hex-values : 49 4E B4 45 4E 4A 45 52 49 4E 47`
I want to remove the special character `B4`.

Now if I remove a regular character (e.g. "I") using the command

```
text=$(printf "$text" | sed "s/\x49/ /g")
```

the command works fine

```
Result  : text=N▒ENJER NG
```

If I want to remove the special character, it seems not to work

```
text=$(printf "$text" | sed "s/\xB4/ /g")  

Result : IN▒ENJERING
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C sed 's/\xB4/ /g'`. Also do not do `printf "$text"` always do `printf "%s\n" "$text"`, the first argument is format.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\o342\o226\o222/ /g' file
```

To find the octal representation use:

```
<<<"IN▒ENJERING" sed -n l
IN\342\226\222ENJERING$
```

Then to replace each octal character prepend `\o` and use as a pattern match.